# Como saber a network que um video pertence?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

Tem como saber qual network um video pertence atraves da api do youtube?

Comment: Como assim? O que é uma network de um vídeo? Em qual linguagem de programação vc está tentando fazer isso? O que vc já conseguiu fazer/obter? Por favor, edite a pergunta para fornecer mais detalhes, caso contrário ninguém vai conseguir te ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei te informar se a API possui essa informação mas uma forma de obter isso é através da meta tag `attribution` que possui a informação de qual network o canal faz parte.

Para recuperar essa informação usando PHP:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8AZT40gH5E");
echo $network = $tags['attribution']; // Endemol_beyond_Brasil
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17872113/5314295

Comment: Exatamente o que precisava! obrigado

Comment: Marque como resposta. :)